# Why does universe level restriction behave differently between inductive family and parameterized inductive type without axiom K in agda

Tags: types, programming-languages, agda, dependent-type, homotopy-type-theory

An observation when defining `List` in agda with `--without-K` enabled:

The following parameterized inductive definition is accepted:

```
data List (A : Set) : Set where
    [] : List A
    _::_ : A → List A → List A
```

but not the equivalent inductive family definition:

```
data List' : Set → Set where 
    []'  : {A : Set} → List' A
    _::'_ : {A : Set} → A → List' A → List' A
```

The error message is `Set₁ is not less or equal than Set`, so I have to change the type from `List' : Set → Set` to `List' : Set → Set₁` in order for it to type-check. If I disable `--without-K`, then agda also correctly type-checks.

I tried to look up why this is the case, e.g., on the page https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/without-k.html it says "When `--without-K` is enabled, some indexed datatypes must be defined in a higher universe level. In particular, the types of all indices should fit in the sort of the datatype." But it doesn't say the reason for such difference between inductive family (indexed datatypes) definition and the parameterized inductive definition. I guess it has something to do with the homotopy model interpretation of the underlying type theory. However I want to know what sort of "bad" thing will happen if the inductive family lives in a smaller universe (syntax and semantics). And how would parameterized inductive definition avoids such issue?